# JQuery ui drop event ? how to know what was dropped?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a tiny javascript which uses JQUERY UI.

When I get the 'drop' event call I would like to know what HTML Element was dropped.
Can somebody tell me how to figure that out.

I know how to figure which HTML element received the event but I don't know how to figure which HTML element was dropped

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable,#draggable2,#draggable3" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
        $( "#draggable,#draggable2,#draggable3" ).droppable({
            accept: "#draggable,#draggable2,#draggable3",
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {


                alert("destination:"+ this.id+" source:"+event.target.id);
                            alert("source is "+"???");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `drop` function it will be `ui.draggable`.

Comment: I saw that but ui.draggable is not an HTML Element. it's something else.

Comment: You can use ```ui.draggable[0]``` to get the HTML element.

Comment: Thanks that works. SO GREAT THANKS !!! Can you explain a bit how it works though... or where it's documented.

Comment: ```ui.draggable``` is simply a jQuery wrapped set of the HTML element that was dropped.  So it's essentially just taking the element and wrapping it via ```$()```.  The only documentation is here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop.